# Calculate `Net Pay` based on `Standard Hours` and `Overtime Hours`

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to have the cell(s) M5, M13, M21, M29 each calculate hours worked * pay rate. Standard pay rate = $20/hour. Overtime, over 40 hours, pay rate =  $30/hour (or time and a half)

(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1naIUcyK5LcnuRpsWqdVabQJuyCD-S7cv-bRoU9xGp4w/edit?usp=sharing)

This formula is beyond me. Just wondering if anyone has worked on something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try in `M5`:*

```js
=min(L5,40)*20+if(L5>40,(L5-40)*30,)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Precisely what I was looking for.